# Monaco JavaScript editor - how change intellisense position to be displayed below the line?

Tags: monaco-editor

I have Monaco editor working with JavaScript content on a web page, I have set up custom type definitions, so the IntelliSense works.

One problem though: hovering mouse above a JavaScript statement close to the top of the editor window displays IntelliSense above the statement, so most of it is positioned outside the editor window - not visible to the user.

Is there a way to change intellisense positioning to force it displayed below the targeted statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don’t think this will help with positioning, but have you tried using:

fixedOverflowWidgets: true

This assigns a position: fixed in widgets, which means content will not get clipped by parent content set to overflow: hidden/auto.

Comment: This actually fixed all positioning problems.